# Excel auto populate DATE from one worksheet to another in same workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I really hope someone can help me with this. I'm getting super frustrated.

I have a specific cell (F3) on sheet1 that I'm using the DATE function to show a specific date (not the current date). I want to be able to type that date into that cell and have it auto populate the same date in a different cell on another worksheet (sheet5). Everything I have read refers to a range or array or table. I need a specific cell to populate that data to a specific cell on another worksheet in the same workbook.

Can someone please help me. The concept seems pretty straight forward but all the answers I've seen are soooooooo freakin complicated. Simple issue=simple solution. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of putting `=sheet1!F3` into the cell on sheet5?  If not, explain better. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out. And yes. It was a very simple solution to a very simple problem. I'm not sure if it's the fact that I'm using Office 365 or what not but I got it to do what I wanted it to do.

Original issue: I couldn't figure out how to link cells between worksheets in the same workbook so that the info in let's say cell F3 on sheet 1 of the workbook would automatically show up in different cell on another sheet in the same workbook.

Solution: since typing =sheet1!F3 in the cell didn't work like everything I've read said it should. Apparently I needed to add a single apostrophe before/after the sheet name and number. Example: ='sheet1'!F3

Here's a link to a youtube video I found that explains it very simply as well as shows you how to link cells from different workbooks as well. I hope this helps everyone. [Link Cells In Different Excel Worksheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UM_dmXRZRMU&t=70s)